# asp.net drop down list SelectedIndexChanged not working

Tags: c#

I have 2 functions:

1. creating the drop down list
2. event handler of it (trying to redirect .. just to know it's working).

but it doesn't work..
help please :(

**creating drop down list:**

```
DropDownList createUsersDropDownList(ShiftClass shift, string selectedDate,int dayNumber)//creating the drop down list of users of shift
{
    DropDownList output=new DropDownList();
    output.Items.Add(new ListItem("","0"));
    List<UserClass> listOfUsers = new List<UserClass>();
    //arrange.watchersRoles = list of roles can watch
    DateTime theDate = DateTime.Parse(selectedDate);
    DBConnect dbConn = new DBConnect();
    using (dbConn.conn)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlGetUserDetails;
        SqlDataReader rsGetUserDetails;
        foreach (int allowedRole in arrange.watchersRoles)//for every role, create userclass
        {
            sqlGetUserDetails= new SqlCommand("select ID from dbo.Users where roleID=" + allowedRole, dbConn.conn);//calling the allowed users with id
            rsGetUserDetails = sqlGetUserDetails.ExecuteReader();
            if (rsGetUserDetails.HasRows)
                while(rsGetUserDetails.Read())  //get the details from db
                    listOfUsers.Add(new UserClass((int)rsGetUserDetails["ID"]));//adding the user to the list
            rsGetUserDetails.Close();
        }//end foreach role
        dbConn.conn.Close();
    }//end using conn

    ListItem userToAdd;

    foreach (UserClass allowedUser in listOfUsers)//foreach user, add him to the drop down list
    { 

        userToAdd=new ListItem();
        UserClass currentUserInShift = shift.userInShift(shift.shiftID, dateToSql(theDate.AddDays(0).Date));
        if(currentUserInShift!= null )//there is user in this shift
            if (allowedUser.userData.id == currentUserInShift.userData.id)//user is equal ==>  selected
                userToAdd.Selected = true;
        userToAdd.Value=allowedUser.userData.id.ToString();
        userToAdd.Text=allowedUser.userData.firstName + " " + allowedUser.userData.lastName;
        output.Items.Add(userToAdd);

    }

    output.ID = theDate.AddDays(0).Date + "_" + shift.shiftID.ToString();
    output.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(updateUserInShift);
    output.EnableViewState = true;
    output.AutoPostBack = true;

    return output;
}//end createDropDownList
```

**the event handler:**

```
protected void updateUserInShift(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string originalShift;
    string date;
    int userID;

    DropDownList selectedList = (DropDownList)sender;

    originalShift = selectedList.ID;
    Page.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com", true);
}
```

** but nothing happens ... there is a post back but not with the event handler..**

Comment: is BKP is hitting in  `updateUserInShift`

Comment: Did you make  AutoPostBack="True" ?

Comment: take a look at the first function ... output.AutoPostBack = true;

Comment: Could you show the code that is attaching the created DropDownList to the page?

Comment: TableCell ShiftLabel(TableRow shiftTR, ShiftClass shift, int dayNumber)//creating td of scheduled shifts
    {
        TableCell shiftTD= new TableCell();       
        shiftTD.ID = shift.shiftTitle + weekDates[dayNumber];
        shiftTD.CssClass = "headCol";
        userInShift = shift.userInShift(shift.shiftID, dateToSql(selectedDate.Date.AddDays(dayNumber)));
        DropDownList usersDropDownList = createUsersDropDownList(shift, dateToSql(selectedDate.Date.AddDays(dayNumber)), dayNumber);
        shiftTD.Controls.Add(usersDropDownList);
        return shiftTD;//</td>
    }